# Where should I save User and Password values of my React-Native App?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, react-native

I am developing an application in React-Native. I have to make a login with user and password. And this have to be persistent in the device, but I don't know where to save it. SQLite Table? Shared Preferences? Can anybody tell me what could be the most correctly and secure option?  It have to work both Android and iOS.

Greetings!

Comment: Can you tell us why the password must be persisted? Client-side, the only proper way to store it is in the brain of the user --> it is a secret to prove the backend system your identity. If it can be intercepted, it's no longer a secret and that's why you mustn't store it client-side. Can't you store some kind of OAuth2 refresh token instead?
If you really have to store it, which i don't recommend, you mustn't store it cleartext: it must be in some secure storage only available to your application.

Comment: I need to save the password because I want that the user only Log in one time, and the next time the app log in it automatically. Sorry my english!

Comment: Then I think you should check OAuth2 or OpenIDConnect and the refresh tokens (which are kind of long-life sessions). Check on the internet/Google how other applications are doing, but storing the password doesn't feel like a good solution.

Comment: Look for that kind of thing, it'll give you some good advice ;) https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the Username and password in a central location where it can be accessed from multiple clients (IOS and Android).

Make it easy on yourself and store it in any DB you choose. In order for it to be persistent, don't use `AsyncStorage`, it's not encrypted. For persistence with project version below 0.6, use something like [React native keychain to store secure info in shared preferences.](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain)